# Installing Ubuntu on Lenovo Ideapad 710S-13IKB

Tags: system-installation, bios, ideapad

After doing some Google-ing I see that I have to update my BIOS to install Ubuntu on the machine. Firstly, I have no idea how to perform this update and I'm having trouble finding reliable instructions. Secondly, updating the BIOS seems to render Windows useless so I wonder how I should then go by installing Ubuntu. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: BIOS/UEFI updates are provided (or not) by the manufacturers along with the instructions.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to provide a workaround solution that permits you to install Ubuntu on the Lenovo Ideapad 710S-13IKB without changing or updating the existing BIOS. It would help if you could provide a link to the webpage where it says that you need to update the BIOS to install Ubuntu on that laptop.

Comment: I found this on the Lenovo forum: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Ubuntu-on-710S-13IKB-IdeaPad-laptop/td-p/3609988

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've successfully done this with an Ideapad 710S - I am running xubuntu 17.04 on it as I write this.

Unfortunately, the linux-compatible BIOS is required for linux to see your hard disk. As the readme file for the BIOS explains:

> This BIOS creates an AHCI SATA Controller Mode selection to allow for the installation of the Linux operating system.

For this you'll need: stock windows 10 installed, the linux version of the bios, and a usb key setup with an ubuntu/variant install image.

Find your Linux BIOS here: http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/DS119359

You will need to have the stock windows installed. Simply download the 'Linux-Only' BIOS installer and run it. You may need to make sure certain BIOS settings are used (see the bottom of the post). After which, you should be able to jump your machine into Ubuntu 'try-it' mode from the USB - verify that it can see your hard disk. From there you can install Ubuntu or an Ubuntu variant.

If you don't have windows installed, you will probably need to re-install it in order to flash this new BIOS. You might be able to get away with a FreeDOS USB stick with the new BIOS on it, but my recommendation is to re-install windows to update the BIOS.

Other variants of the 710s (non-13IKB) linux bios links can be found here:

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/Yoga-900-and-Ideapad-710S-Linux-Only-BIOS/ta-p/3466850

My BIOS has these settings:

- 'Configuration' tab set 'SATA Controller Mode' to 'AHCI'
- 'Security' tab set 'Secure Boot to' 'Disabled'
- 'Boot' tab set 'Boot Mode' to 'UEFI'