# Installing Ubuntu on Lenovo Ideapad 710S-13ISK

Tags: lenovo, bios, ideapad

Reading the answer provided here:
[Installing Ubuntu on Lenovo Ideapad 710S-13IKB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946291/installing-ubuntu-on-lenovo-ideapad-710s-13ikb)
I understand that the only way to install Ubuntu seems to update the BIOS using
the  "Linux Only" version available here:
https://support.lenovo.com/ie/en/downloads/ds119359

the point is that there is not way to use Win10 as well, correct ?

And what about if we want to revert the changes, how to put back the previous BIOS ? If Windows is not accessible anymore any way to do from Ubuntu ?

Comment: from the links yoou provided, it seems that the bios needs to be uppdated to allow AHCI mode on the SSD. this does not prevent windows from running but will require that it be reinstalled.

Comment: maybe... but I dont know so much about AHCI, still not sure how window handles AHCI. I dont' want to be locked out....

Answer (score 1):

Windows has drivers for AHCI mode disks. The problem is when you enable AHCI, windows doesn't have the driver installed because it was installed in IDE mode, thus can't mount the disk and boot.
You could ask on Superuser about booting windows into safe mode and getting it to install the driver for AHCI, or reinstall Windows in AHCI mode.
You wouldn't be locked out as the new BIOS should allow you to select between IDE and AHCI. But of course it is advisable to backup important data before doing anything to a system.